# Handlebars.js, Show "No data" for single time When condition fails in registerhelper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement registerHelper in handlebars. I am iterating data in the template. But the problem is that if there are not any matches then there should show "No Data" for only once.
My JSON data is:-

```
{
    "ToDoMilstnCount": {
        "milestone_count": 8,
        "todo_count": 5
    },
    "toDoList": [
        {
            "todo_due_dt_new": "08 May 2016",
            "day_of_todo": "Overdue",
            "todo_id": 2,
            "todo_type": "PERSONAL",
            "todo_description": "ABC 1",
            "todo_owner_id": 4
        },
        {
            "todo_due_dt_new": "10 May 2016",
            "day_of_todo": "Overdue",
            "todo_id": 1,
            "todo_type": "PERSONAL",
            "todo_description": "ABC",
            "todo_owner_id": 4
        },
        {
            "todo_due_dt_new": "13 May 2016",
            "day_of_todo": "Tomorrow",
            "todo_id": 6,
            "todo_type": "PERSONAL",
            "todo_description": "ABC 5",
            "todo_owner_id": 4
        },
        {
            "todo_due_dt_new": "13 May 2016",
            "day_of_todo": "Tomorrow",
            "todo_id": 7,
            "todo_type": "PERSONAL",
            "todo_description": "ABC 6",
            "todo_owner_id": 4,
        }
    ]
}
```

My register helper is:-

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("overdue", function (type, options) {
    if (type === "Overdue") {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
Handlebars.registerHelper("Today", function (type, options) {
    if (type === "Today") {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And my template is:-

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    {{#toDoList}}{{#Today day_of_todo}}<tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px 0;">
            <p style="font-size: 14px; color: #222; margin: 0px;">{{todo_description}}</p>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #ddd;">{{todo_due_dt_new}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/Today}}
    {{/toDoList}}
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    {{#toDoList}}{{#overdue day_of_todo}}<tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px 0;">
            <p style="font-size: 14px; color: #222; margin: 0px;">{{todo_description}}</p>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #ddd;">{{todo_due_dt_new}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>{{/overdue}}{{/toDoList}}
</table>
```

Now the problem is if there is not any To-Do for today. then I need to show "No To-Do for today" in the template for only once.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Shivam